# How can I stop sagemaker pipeline pausing my jobs after a day

Tags: pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I have a long running job that'll probably take over a day to run. It's just collecting initial data. However, after a day the job is paused automatically, I have to go in everyday to hit the resume button in the pipeline execution. How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Good chances the root cause is a SageMaker training job that runs for more than 24Hrs, and timeouts if you didn't increase the default [max_run](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html):

> max_run (int) – Timeout in seconds for training (default: 24 * 60 * 60). After this amount of time Amazon SageMaker terminates the job regardless of its current status.

Then when you resume the job, it probably picks up training from a checkpoint and therefore able to eventually finish where the last attempt is less than a day.